# Excel adding dates to specific date format

Tags: excel, date

I have dates coming out of a database into a column that have this format:

Column K

`AUG-14-2015 08:31:32 AM
AUG-12-2015 06:10:03 PM
AUG-12-2015 05:17:51 PM`

I want to add like '2.2' days to each of these and put them in Column L.  I have formatted the column in this format:

`mmm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM`

I wasn't sure if the dashes are causing the problem, but when I do a =K15+2.2 I get a !VALUE.  Any ideas what I need to do?  Thanks.

Comment: Excel is a very literal program. It doesn't know how to add two days. You'll either have to manually do it, or create a macro that tells Excel how to work with the date format. 2.2 isn't interpreted as 2.2 days. It's interpreted as just the raw number 2.2.

Comment: @DeeWBee :  That is not the case; when a cell is date formatted, it has a value in days since the start of the epoch (1900), and is merely displayed per the specified format (customisable).  When you take a correctly date/time formatted cell and add a value to it, the result is also interpreted as a date/time.  In this case I presume the cell is not correctly formatted.

Comment: What do you mean by 2.2 days?  Would that mean 2 days and 2/10 of a day, i.e. 4 hours and 48 minutes?  Excel can calculate dates without much issue (i.e. Jan 1, 2015 + 1 = Jan 2, 2015), but I'm not sure about *increments* of a day.  That we'd probably need a formula for.

Comment: @BruceWayne yes that is exactly what I mean, they are not all 2.2, they might be .74 or 5.45 days, etc.  I just figured Excel would know how to do those calcs already, if not I need a little help getting a formula set up.

Comment: yes the problem looks like slashes AUG-14-2015 08:31:32 AM I changed to AUG/14/2015 08:31:32 AM then added 2.2 and it set the date to AUG-16-2015 1:19:32 PM, but how do I deal with that specifically formatted date coming into the sheet?   No need to convert the partial days, excel appears to know how to do it

Comment: I'm working on something - My thinking is to take your "add 2.2 days" and change that into minutes. Then, take your original time and change to minutes, then just add the minutes together, then "add" to the date (in case it's over 1440 minutes, which is a day).

Comment: @DeeWBee, that's not quite right. Internally, excel stores dates/times as numbers. Adding to 2.2 to a date/time adds 2.2 seconds. If you want to add 2.2 days, you should add (2.2 * 86400).

Comment: @JonathanM I stand corrected!

Comment: @BruceWayne: Excel stores date/time as the number of days since 1 Jan 1900, it has no problem with fractions of a day.

Comment: @JonathanM : Date/Time is stored in units of days since 1 Jan 1900, not seconds, so adding 2.2 does indeed add 2 days, 4 hours and 48 minutes.

Comment: @Clifford - are you sure? Is there some special "adding" format? I couldn't get his cells to just add by `+2.2`.

Comment: @BruceWayne : See my posted answer.  The cell must be date formatted and be a valid date - the strings from dave111's database are not accepted as valid dates - I am guessing due to his locale being day/month order rather then month/day.

Comment: @Clifford - d'oh! Nicely done, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting, it seems that while you can specify a date format `"mmm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"`, the actual entry into the cells must be either a date in the system wide locale specific format, or a number of days since 1 January 1900.

So for example when you set a cell's format to custom:

`"mmm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"`

In my case (Windows 10 default UK locale settings, Excel 2010) for `AUG-12-2015 06:10:03 PM`, I can enter any of:

- 12/08/2015 06:10:03 PM
- 12/08/2015 18:10:03
- 42228.26

And also exchange the month 08 for Aug or AUG in any case and change the '/' for '-' in the dates.

For cells formatted `"mmm-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM"`, the output for any of the above inputs is:

- Aug-12-2015 06:10:03 PM

Note that there does not appear to be a means to force all-capitals for the month.

Note also that if you enter a date/time in the locale format it is automatically recognised and formatted as date/time.

So really your only option is to either change the format of the source data, pre-process the data into locale date/time format, or write a macro to do it within the spreadsheet.  It may also work perhaps if you change your locale settings (System Settings, Language & Time), but that is perhaps less than satisfactory because it will affect date presentation for the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid VBA, then you can add a column("L") next to your data and enter:

`=SUBSTITUTE(K1,"-","/")`

Another solution would be to write code to do just that to your existing "K" Column